# Загрузка/предзагрузка/отображение шрифтов

Tags: html, css, шрифты

Коллеги, всем добрый день.
На сайте использую сторонние шрифты. Подключаю их с помощью font-face.

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "Montserrat";
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 300;
   font-display: fallback;
   src:
      url("../fonts/Montserrat-Light.woff2") format("woff2"),
      url("../fonts/Montserrat-Light.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
   font-family: "Montserrat";
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 400;
   font-display: fallback;
   src:
      url("../fonts/Montserrat-Regular.woff2") format("woff2"),
      url("../fonts/Montserrat-Regular.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
   font-family: "Montserrat";
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 500;
   font-display: fallback;
   src:
      url("../fonts/Montserrat-Medium.woff2") format("woff2"),
      url("../fonts/Montserrat-Medium.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
   font-family: "Montserrat";
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 600;
   font-display: fallback;
   src:
      url("../fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.woff2") format("woff2"),
      url("../fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.woff") format("woff");
}
```

Сайт уже размещен на хостинге. Проверил отображение во всех браузерах, на всех устройствах.
Но бывает так, что при открытие сайта шрифт все равно не подгружается. После обновления страницы (даже по истечению некоторого времени), если шрифт сразу не подключился, все остается без изменений.
Хочется как всегда, что бы было хорошо.
Подскажите пожалуйста какое-нибудь решение. Или может мне что-то необходимо поменять в моем представленном подходе.
Буду очень благодарен.

Спасибо